# I can't run an .x86 file

Tags: executable

I recently downloaded ubuntu linux on my chromebook and i love it! I also downloaded a game called: Game of the year 420 blaze it. I had it installed on my windows computer and i also wanted it on my chromebook. I downloaded the .zip file, found the .x86 file, extracted it into my downloads file, made it an executable program in the properties, and then a new thing pops up when i right-click the file. It is called "execute". I'm not familiar with ubuntu linux at all, but at least i knew it would probably run it. I clicked it and nothing happened. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Open a shell, run the executable from there and look if there are any errors being printed. If there are errors, please append those (inside a code-block) to your question.

Comment: Most Chromebooks can not run x86 (That is, software compiled for Intel / AMD processors). If your Chromebook isn't an Intel one: Check if there's an ARM build of the game,  if the game is open source, you can also compile it yourself. Otherwise you may be out of luck.